# Run map reduce functions as a job in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

Running a map reduce functions as a job in mongodb. Is it possible?

If I updated the collection with some data then the map reduce functions should run automatically as a job & produce the result in the output collection with latest data.

Can we achieve this in mongodb?

Answer (score 1):

No. You would need to schedule these outside MongoDB.

What you are asking for sounds like it may be better suited to being a [View within Couchbase](http://www.couchbase.com/docs//couchbase-manual-2.0/couchbase-views-operation.html).

Comment: I am looking for map reduce functions to executed automatically.Example: var map = function(){some code...}. var reduce = function(key,values){some code..} ...db.Collection.mapReduce(map,reduce,{ out: "Outputcollection",query:{some filter}}); .. I have to execute this functions automatically in mongodb as a job.

Comment: You *cannot* run it 'automatically' triggered by some change in the collection.

Comment: ok but, Is there any other way of implementation that I can do using cronjob or java?

Comment: Yes, you can run Map-Reduce from whatever MongoDB driver you are using, but the logic as to what job to run and when to run it is all yours, MongoDB itself doesn't help with that.